# The verb "fa" to express someone's job

Tags: verbs

I am using an app to learn Italian, and it has been showing me sentences such as,

> "Mio cugino fa l'avvocato."

I understand that this means, "my cousin is a lawyer," or, "my cousin works as a lawyer". However, I don't understand the difference between it and,

> "Mio cugino è un avvocato."

Do these sentences mean exactly the same thing, or is there a subtle difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per your understanding there is no substantial difference. "Mio cugino è un avvocato" means "my cousin is a lawyer", that is your cousin graduated from law school but, if he's unemployed you won't say  "Mio cugino fa l'avvocato" because it means "my cousin works as a lawyer".
I suppose it's the same subtle difference there is in English.

Ciao, Fabrizio.